# Navigation text within circle list-item doesn't shrink fluidly. Instead text starts sticking out.

Tags: html, css

I rounded my nav list-items and have centered the link text inside of them. However, when I shrink the browser window, as I am trying to create a fluid website, the circle re-sizes while the text does not re-size proportionally along with it.

I thought this had something to do with the padding or width values of either the li a or the li. However, I have tried adjusting fixed values to percent values, yet, the problem still persists.

Below is the HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="circle"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="circle"><a href="coding.html">Coding</a></li>
        <li class="circle"><a href="health.html">Health</a></li>
        <li class="circle"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Below is the CSS

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

nav a {
  padding: 3em;
}

.circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this at the beginning of your css :

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zm0Ljuv5/2/)

Comment: the answer of @bobdye is completely out of subject

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You seem to have been able to keep the words inside the circles, but can the words be made to display in their entirety (while still being in the circles)? 

In a full browser window the words are fine; it is when I scrunch up the browser window that they stay unchanging while the circles get smaller.

Comment: @Eddy- So, I ended up adding the overflow property to the (nav li) and that did the trick as far as keeping the words from breaking out of the circle! Thanks!

Sorry if I reiterate myself here, how I would I go about making the words adjust in size so that they are always fully displayed in their entirety within the circle? word-wrap?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to make the margin a percentage, e.g.

```
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 7%;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/kwrtkoad/#base) and see if it's what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly. Although, making the margin a % may be a good idea also.

What I wish to do is keep the letters inside the circles as I minimize/scrunch up the browser window. At the moment, this isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a way using just CSS to make the text stay inside the circles as they change size.

I suggest you take a look at [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/), which is a well-regarded Javascript script to do just that.